# How to create a single C source file that includes two header files?

Tags: c

Is there a way to setup a single project with different configurations (or a different method) that point to the unique header files.

I want to create a single C project that contains two header files (e.g `header1.h` and `header2.h`). In my .c source file I have defined two configurations. e.g:

```
int main() 
{ 
#ifdef _print1_ 
#include "header1.h" 
#elif _print2_
#include "header2.h" 
#endif 
return 0; 
}
```

Now for example I want to just print any string as output. So what I want to declare in my header file. That is `#ifdef print1` needs to execute `header1.h` and `#elif print2` needs to execute `header1.h` .Please note that I need to have a header file in different folders with the same file name.

Can you please any one assist me on this?

Comment: What? Why? If the `header1.h` and `header2.h` files can meaningfully be included in the middle of `main()`, that implies that they contain code, and should be named `.c`. Where is `_print1` and `_print2` defined, on the command line?

Comment: I think you should explain what's your final goal here, because I feel there might be a different more correct way to achieve it.

Comment: That a perfect example of a very very bad programming idea.  And having the include inside the function is another one.

Comment: Seems like a good candidate as an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem

Comment: What you mean by "execute `header1.h`"? Header files can't be "executed" in general sense.

Answer (score 0):

*If* you do it, do it this way:

```
#ifdef _print1_ 
#  include "header1.h" 
#elif _print2_
#  include "header2.h" 
#endif 

int main(void) 
{ 
  ...

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I want to declare it,for example to print any string to console.I want to call the header1.h for _print1_ configuration.As well as call the header2.h for _print2_ configuration.Now how i declare this in header file??.so while the _print1_ is selected it want to call header.h and execute the output.

Comment: You can't *call* header files. You can only *include* them.

Comment: @nisha: "*Now how i declare this in header file*" that's probably worth another question. This question should include what you tried and where you failed.